# Haversine Formula On Large Areas

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation, geometry

I'm working on a search functionality for my site. It has a search by place filter with radius using the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). Here's my query from this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator):

```
SELECT id, 
       ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians(37)) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                     Radians(lng) - Radians(-122)) + 
                              Sin( 
                              Radians(37)) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) AS distance 
FROM   markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER  BY distance 
LIMIT  0, 20;
```

This works if I enter small areas, for example "Bondi Junction NSW, Australia" but if I enter large areas like "NSW, Austraiia"which is a state, it doesn't work. I've calculated its [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) using the formula and its very far from the small areas' great circle distance under it. Is there another formula/algorithm for this? or I'm just missing something here?

Comment: There's an even potentially bigger problem, which is that the great circle distance may not correspond with the actual path someone would take to get from point A to point B.  But, in the absence of an alternative, e.g. the Google Places API, this may be the best you can do.

Comment: Vincenty's formulae https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae